# Github 500 error the page can not be loaded

Tags: web, github, server, web-development-server

please help me , ı cant create a repository due to the error. after clicking the continue to layouts , 500 error appears on the page. ı refreshed it but ıt didnt work. ı use opera and stil having same problem.

Comment: This sounds like a github problem that we can't help solve...

Answer (score 5):

500 is a server error, it usually happens when GitHub server encounters a problem and is down. You can check [github status website](https://githubstatus.com) to keep track.

Usually problems like this should already be reported; all you have to do is wait for the server to recover then everything should work. In the meantime you can of course, still commit and work locally in git.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 is the HTTP error code for Internal Server Error, so it should be an error on GitHub side.

You can read GitHub Status here: https://www.githubstatus.com/

If that is down too, check Twitter: https://www.twitter.com/githubstatus

If even that brings no answers, search on Twitter: https://www.twitter.com/search?q=GitHub%20500%20error

Check also on GitHub subreddit (https://old.reddit.com/r/github) if people are going crazy.

If you have a VPN try logging as other countries to see if it's just you or everyone.